# Extracting numbers in text file

Tags: python, bash, powershell, text, extract

I have a text file which came from excel. I dont know how to take five digits after a specific character.

I want to take only five digits after `#ACA` in a text file.

my text is like:

```
ERROR_MESSAGE
(((#ACA16018)|(#ACA16019))&(#AQV71767='')&(#AQV71765='2'))?1:((#AQV71765='4')?1:((#AQV71767$'')?(((#AQV71765='1')|(#AQV71765='3'))?1:'Hasar veya Lehe Hukuk seçebilirsiniz'):'Rücu sıra numarasını yazıp Hasar veya Lehe Hukuk seçebilirsiniz'))
Rücu Oranı Girilmesi Zorunludur...'
#ACA17660
#ACA16560
#ACA15623
#ACA17804
BU ALANI BOŞ GEÇEMEZSİNİZ.EKSPER RAPORU GELMEDEN  DY YE GERİ GÖNDEREMEZSİNİZ. PERT İHBARI VARSA PERT ÇALINMA OPERASYONU AKTİVİTESİ OLUŞTURULMALIDIR.
(#TSC[T008UNSMAS;FIRM_CODE=2 AND UNIT_TYPE='SG' AND UNIT_NO=#AQV71830]>0)?1:'Girdiğiniz değer fihristte yoktur'
#ACA17602
#ACA17604
#ACA56169
BU ALANI BOŞ GEÇEMEZSİNİZ
#ACA17606
#ACA17608
(#AQV71835='')?'Boş geçilemez':1
Lütfen Gönderilecek Kişinin Mail Adresini Giriniz ! '
LÜTFEN RED NEDENİNİ GİRİNİZ.
EKSİK BİLGİ / BELGE ALANINA GİRMİŞ OLDUĞUNUZ DEĞER YANLIŞ VEYA GEÇERŞİZDİR!!! LÜTFEN KONTROL EDİP TEKRAR DENEYİNİZ.'
BU ALAN BOŞ GEÇİLEMEZ. ÖDEME YAPILMADAN EK ÖDEME SÜRECİNİ BAŞLATAMAZSINIZ.
ONAYLANDI VE REDDEDİLDİ SEÇENEKLERİNİ KULLANAMAZSINIZ
BU ALAN BOŞ GEÇİLEMEZ.EVRAKLARINIZI , VARSA EKSPER RAPORUNU VE MUALLAĞI KONTROL EDİNİZ. 
Muallak Tutarını kontrol ediniz.
'OTO BRANŞINDA REDDEDİLDİ NEDENİ SEÇMELİSİNİZ'
'OTODIŞI BRANŞINDA REDDEDİLDİ NEDENİ SEÇMELİSİNİZ'
(#AQV70003$'')?((#TSC[T001HASIHB;FIRM_CODE=#FP10100 AND COMPANY_CODE=2 AND CLAIM_NO=#AQV70003]$0)?1:'Bu dosya sistemde bulunmamaktadır'):'Bu alan boş geçilemez'
(#AQV70503='')?'Bu alan boş geçilemez.':((#ACA18635=1)?1:'Mağdura ait uygun kriterli ödeme kaydı mevcut değildir.')
(#AQV71809=0)?'Boş geçilemez':1
(#FD101AQV71904_AFDS<0)?'Tarih bugünün tarihinden büyük olamaz
```

I want to take every 5 digits which comes after `#ACA`, so:

`16018`, `16019`, `17660`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell solution:

```
$contet = Get-Content -Raw 'your_file'
$match = [regex]::Matches($contet, '#ACA(\d{5})')
$match | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
}
```

**Output:**

```
16018
16019
17660
16560
15623
17804
17602
17604
56169
17606
17608
18635
```

Comment: How can i uniq sort the output after i run the yourscript.ps1 ?

Comment: Just pipe the result to the Sort cmdlet using `| sort`

Answer (score 5):

```
grep -oP '#ACA\K[0-9]{5}' file.txt
```

- `#ACA\K` will match `#ACA` but not printed as part of output
- `[0-9]{5}` five digits following `#ACA`

If variable number of digits are needed, use

```
grep -oP '#ACA\K[0-9]+' file.txt
```

Comment: You could also add limit '5' to the  number of digits.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know or don't like regular expressions, you can do this, although the code is a bit longer :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pattern = '#ACA'
    filename = 'yourfile.txt'
    res = list()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:  # open 'yourfile.txt' in byte-reading mode
        for line in f:  # for each line in the file
            for s in line.split(pattern)[1:]:  # split the line on '#ACA'
                try:
                    nb = int(s[:5])  # take the first 5 characters after as an int
                    res.append(nb)  # add it to the list of numbers we found
                except (NameError, ValueError):  # if conversion fails, that wasn't an int
                    pass
    print res  # if you want them in the same order as in the file
    print sorted(res)  # if you want them in ascending order
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
import re

print(re.findall("#ACA(\d+)",str_var))
```

If you have the whole text in the variable `str_var`

Output:

```
['16018', '16019', '17660', '16560', '15623', '17804', '17602', '17604', '56169', '17606', '17608', '18635']
```

Answer (score 2):

`re.findall(r'#ACA(\d{5})', str_var)`

Answer (score 2):

`[x[:5] for x in content.split("#ACA")[1:]]`

Comment: You're welcome but no need to clutter the post with 'thanks' everywhere, it is generally assumed that people are thankful ; ) Or if you really 'need' to thank everyone, just leave a general comment :)